# past or present with 'alleging'

Tags: tense, reported-speech

"In order to take the remedial action in the area, the company sent a work permission request form to XXX ; however XXX rejected the company's form by alleging that the area in question **is** not yet taken over."

Should I use "was" instead of "is" in the bold part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice between *was* and *is* depends on where you want your time focus to lie. If you are speaking the situation only as it stood at the time of X's action, use *was*; but if you wish to indicate that the situation is still in effect at the time you are writing, use *is*.

(I'm rewriting your *alleging*, since that seems to prejudice the conclusion and confuse the temporal issue.)

> ... XXX rejected the company's form, on the grounds that the area **was** not yet taken over. When the area was taken over in 2012, the company resubmitted and XXX permitted the remedial action to go forward.
>
> ... XXX rejected the company's form, on the grounds that the area **was** not yet taken over. We maintain, however, that the area had already been taken over at that time, and XXX's rejection was improper.
>
> ... XXX rejected the company's form, on the grounds that the area **is** not yet taken over. We have now initiated the takeover process, which we hope will be completed in the next few months.

It should be noted, however, that **is** is very stiff here: the present perfect would be more idiomatic:

> ... XXX rejected the company's form, on the grounds that the area **has** not yet **been** taken over.

Comment: thanks for the response but what is the problem with "alleging" in the sentence ? my intention is to present that XXX's behavior has no ground and null.

Comment: @discoversf I changed it because 1) Your form, *reject by alleging*, is unidiomatic: an allegation may be the grounds for a rejection but not its means.  2) As you see from my examples, the factuality of the allegation has a bearing on the tense employed, and the examples are clearer if that factuality is addressed directly rather than merely implied. 3) Unless you are running for office, narratives of this sort are better handled with dispassionate recitations of fact than with insinuations and sneers.